# postgis raster to postgres database

Tags: qgis, raster, geoserver, postgresql, raster2pgsql

hi Im trying to access my raster file in QGIS by connecting postgresql database. 
I can see my raster in qgis but I get this error :

Geçersiz Katman: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset PG: dbname=geoserver user=postgres port=5430 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=boston: Couldn't establish a database connection Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: PG: dbname=geoserver user=postgres port=5430 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=boston

as soon as I click it.

I'm using raster2pgsql for raster data and here is the sample of it:

raster2pgsql.exe -s 32637 -I -c -M -C -b 1,2 -M -l 2,4 C:\GDAL_Translate\boston_subset.tif -F -t 250x250 public.boston | psql -U postgres -d geoserver -h localhost -p 5430

Is there a problem in my raster2pgsql code ?
or 
ıs there a problem occurs while connecting to QGIS ?

Comment: what happens if you run raster2pgsql.exe from cmd? Do you get all the tips listed?
Try creating a new copy of the .tif file (export from QGIS) and trying it again.

Comment: it is my problem exactly ... and I do not know what I have to do